# How to get unique data out of an Array?

Tags: json, object, filter, sencha-touch-2, store

I want to get only unique records out of my Array/ JSON.

My Object looks like this:

```
        [
{
"name":"SAP R3 Vertriebskenntnisse",
"ontocat":"SAP_R3_Vertrieb"
},
{
"name":"Kenntnisse SAP-ISU",
"ontocat":"KenntnisseSAPISU"
},
{
"name":"Microsoft Office",
"ontocat":"MicrosoftOffice"
},
{
"name":"SAP",
"ontocat":"SAP"
},
{
"name":"SAP R3 Vertriebskenntnisse",
"ontocat":"SAP_R3_Vertrieb"
},
{
"name":"SAP",
"ontocat":"SAP"
},
{
"name":"SAP",
"ontocat":"SAP"
},
{
"name":"Kenntnisse SAP-MM",
"ontocat":"KenntnisseSAPMM"
},
{
"name":"SAP",
"ontocat":"SAP"
},
{
"name":"SAP",
"ontocat":"SAP"
}
]
```

so how you see there are a lot of entries with the same name.

What can I do to get only a unique entry left ?

For further reasons with a Sencha Store. The object above is added to an JSON Store. Perhaps there is a easier way to isolate the values.

Thanks in advance and please ask if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick Sencha Touch controller with a removeDuplicates function that fits your scenario, here is the code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function(application) {
        console.log('INIT MAIN');

        var json = '[{"name":"SAP R3 Vertriebskenntnisse","ontocat":"SAP_R3_Vertrieb"},{"name":"Kenntnisse SAP-ISU","ontocat":"KenntnisseSAPISU"},{"name":"Microsoft Office","ontocat":"MicrosoftOffice"},{"name":"SAP","ontocat":"SAP"},{"name":"SAP R3 Vertriebskenntnisse","ontocat":"SAP_R3_Vertrieb"},{"name":"SAP","ontocat":"SAP"},{"name":"SAP","ontocat":"SAP"},{"name":"Kenntnisse SAP-MM","ontocat":"KenntnisseSAPMM"},{"name":"SAP","ontocat":"SAP"},{"name":"SAP","ontocat":"SAP"}]',
            arr = Ext.JSON.decode(json),
            output;

        output = this.removeDuplicates(arr);

        console.log(output);
    },

    removeDuplicates: function(arr) {
        var nameList = [],
            output = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            //check if the nameList array has an instance of the name
            if (nameList.indexOf(arr[i].name) === -1) {
                //push a reference of the name to the temporary nameList array
                nameList.push(arr[i].name);
                //push the object to the output array
                output.push(arr[i]);
            }
        };

        return output;
    }
});
```